# Custom post type, custom taxonomy, query posts only from taxonomy (children of)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query-posts

I have a custom post type (portfolio-type) with a custom hierarchical taxonomy (portfolio-category)

Now I would like to query only posts from potrfolio-type, so i do:

```
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
query_posts( '&post_type=portfolio-type&paged=' . $paged );
```

And till here, everything works great. Now, I would like to query only posts, that are in any, of children custom taxonomy "categories" of a custom taxonomy category with given ID.

So I tried:

```
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio-type',
    'cat' => $CAT_ID,
    'paged' => $paged,  
);
query_posts( $query_args );
```

Failed (no results), but I understand Why. those posts are not in standard category, but in custom taxonomy's category, so looking at wp Codex, this is what I came with:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio-type',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $CAT_ID
    )
);
```

Failed again, but this time all custom posts from portfolio-type post_type displays (tax_query doesnt work, whatever ID i put there result is all the same)

What am I missing?

Comment: sory, correcting, its ok over there ;)

Comment: I mean I have it correctly in my code, and still it doesnt filter anything :(

Comment: I can see now, was not clear from you original question. Next hint from the docs: *Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays (it takes an array of arrays)"* - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query - You don't have that. Wrap it inside another `array(...)`, compare with the example there. - If something does not work as thought, check with the docs first, double-check if everything has been written properly.

Comment: And that dear harke is a clue :). Please write as an answer.

Comment: How about you answer your own question? The learning effect will be better for you and I must admit, I just left a comment and a link here, so write a nice answer your own, accept it and this makes it looking better then ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in not reading documentation carefully enough ;)

As it stands in http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query in 'tax_query' part, "tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays" so the correct part of code would be:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio-type',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $CAT_ID
        )       
    ),
);
```

The missing array() in existing array() was a problem.
Thanks hakre :).